# Customize Wordpress WooCommerce checkout page and Payment processing style

Tags: php, html, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, checkout

I am trying to edit my Wordpress WooCommerce checkout page to remove the space above the PayPal checkout buttons but I don't know where I should start off. I feel like this can be easily done just by editing code but I'm not really familiar with HTML and CSS. My [website](https://isetupedia.com)

My website checkout currently looks like:
[image: Desktop view]

[image: mobile view]

My website is [www.isetupedia.com](http://www.isetupedia.com)

But I'm trying to make it look like this:
[image: desired desktop view]

[image: desired mobile view]

Comment: @Junky thanks ! It helped eliminate a big chunk of the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rid of some space with a bit of CSS

```
.woocommerce-checkout #payment {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.woocommerce-checkout #payment div.form-row.place-order {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```